# WPF tab not enabled by parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF application which is (mostly) using MVVM.  My problem is that I've got a tab control (it's a nested tab control actually) which is behaving oddly.  A parent control is disabled during lengthy background processing (which is the behavior that I want!), but when the background stuff finishes and the parent re-enables itself, one of the nested tabs stays disabled.  And the offending tab *changes* depending on which one was selected prior to the background operation; sometimes the 2nd tab will stay disabled, and sometimes the 3rd tab stays disabled.

I do not actually touch the "IsEnabled" property of individual tabs, either through data binding or through code-behind.  Only the parent control (which is a Grid in case that matters) gets disabled.

I'd appreciate any tactics for debugging this; What reasons would cause one tab to be treated differently from the others?

The background processing is not actually necessary to reproduce the problem.  It also happens by simply disabling and reenabling the parent Grid in the code-behind:

```
private void test1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myGrid.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void test2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myGrid.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

EDIT: I may have narrowed the problem down to the following Style.  If I temporarily disable the style by adding a key to it then the problem goes away; but of course I would like to keep the visual appearance of my tabs of possible:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">

                <Grid Height="{Binding Path=HeaderHeight, ElementName=uc}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                                Background="{StaticResource TabItem_BackgroundBrush_Unselected}"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem_BorderBrush_Selected}"
                                Margin="{StaticResource TabItemMargin_Selected}"
                                BorderThickness="2,1,1,0"
                                CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                                >
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem_BorderBrush_Selected}"
                                BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                                Margin="0"
                                Name="BottomBorder"
                                >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header"
                                          Margin="7,2,12,2"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- TabItem appearance when NOT selected -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="90" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_Border_Unselected}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_TextBrush_Unselected}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Margin"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItemMargin_Base}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <!-- TabItem appearance when disabled -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="80" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_BackgroundBrush_Disabled}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_TextBrush_Disabled}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <!-- TabItem appearance when hovering -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="99" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TabItem_TextBrush_Hover}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_HoverBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="2,1,1,1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BottomBorder" Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_HoverBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Margin"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItemMargin_Hover}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <!-- TabItem appearance when active/selected -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_BorderBrush_Selected}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItem_BackgroundBrush_Selected}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BottomBorder" Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="1,1,1,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TabItem_TextBrush_Selected}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Margin"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItemMargin_Selected}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Definitely going to need to see the actual xaml defining the control

Comment: Are always the unselected `TabItem`s disabled? Or just one of them 3, regardless of the selected one?

Comment: It's just 1 of them.  The one that stays disabled seems to be whichever tab is to the left of the selected one (if the 1st tab is selected then the last tab stays disabled).

Comment: I think the problem stems from the fact that several triggers change the same properties. The final values now depend on the order the properties are changed. Try a multi tigger or set different properties (e.g. color and opacity)

Comment: You appear to be correct re: the triggers.  If I remove them entirely then the tabs starting working correctly (but look totally wrong :)).  My first attempt at using MultiTriggers didn't solve the issue, though; I tried adding IsEnabled=true to the non-disabled states.  Looks like this is going to take some experimentation to find the right combination of properties.